# How to 'programmatically' set initial value of a collection variable in Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

I am using a test script in Postman to set a collection variable based on the response received from a request. Following is an excerpt of the code written in the **Tests** tab for a `GET https://swapi.dev/api/species` request:

```js
// script to get species with average height > 100
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
const tallSpeciesCount = responseJson.results.filter(species => species.average_height > 100).length;
pm.collectionVariables.set("talls", tallSpeciesCount);
```

The function `pm.collectionVariables.set()` only sets the **current** value of the `talls` collection variable and NOT the **initial** value. The latter remains blank.

#### Alternative with a 'Glitch'

An alternative can be to go to the collection the request belongs to and click on the **Variables** tab. Then manually click on the three dots appearing at the end of the row of `talls` variable and click on **Persist** option in the dropdown menu. One problem with this approach is that it is manual and involves the GUI to update the preference of a variable. Another bigger problem is that the initial value never gets updated when the response results into some other value hence the inconsistency with current value.

**Example explaining the second problem:**
The first time the request is sent and if the response results into `x`, the current value is set to `x` but the initial value remains blank. If the 'Persist' option is chosen, the initial value is set to `x` too (given that the current value is `x`). However, when the request is hit again and this time if the response returns value `y`, the current value is updated to `y` but the initial value still remains `x`.

**So, the elaborated question is how to set the initial value as well as the current value 'programmatically' in Postman keeping the initial value consistent with the current value?**

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9847

THis was removed from version 8 , but a open feature request is there for the same

Comment: I am running into the same problem more or less, basically I want to chain requests so that I can set a collection variable from the response of one request, then use that collection variable in the following request. This works only if you run the two requests manually from the UI, but it doesn't work while I am running a collection of requests in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't programmatically set an initial value, but you can programmatically persist an initial value by using the Postman API to update the environment value. Refer to section "[Persist variables between runs](https://blog.postman.com/how-to-persist-postman-variables/#persist-variables-between-runs)" of this blog post, and see [this code sample](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/1559645-374325e1-34cd-447c-8fda-66f1a8cc7cb5).

> To programmatically persist variables in a collection-based monitor or while using Newman, you can include a separate API call to the Postman API within your collection to update the environment storing the variable.